# Set datatype in C# with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, entity-framework-core, set

I have this enum in my C# code:

```
enum MyOptionsEnum
{
   Option1,
   Option2,
   Option3
};
```

I have an entity which uses this enum:

```
class OrderEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    ...
    public MyOptionsEnum Options { get; set; }
}
```

This code works fine if I want to choose ONE option for each order.

What I want to do is to allow user to check 1,2 or 3 options (or 0). This is what I call a "set" of options.

Here is what I've done:

```
enum MyOptionsEnum
{
   Option1 = 1,
   Option2 = 2,
   Option3 = 4
};
```

And here is what I've done in my code if i want to set Option1 and Option3 on a specific order:

```
order.Options = MyOptionsEnum.Option1 | MyOptionsEnum.Option3;
```

It works but it is ugly for me.

Let's imagine another developer which adds a new option in the enum and forget to set a multiple of 2 in the value. It won't work...

My question: is there a "Set" datatype in C# / Entity Framework ?

Thanks

Comment: Most relational databases don't support multiple values in a single column because it defies normalization rules. Those value should be in a separate table. Bit flags are okay in a single integer column as long as you don't need to do anything with them in SQL.

Comment: If you want more than 1 choice in your selection then you should use a one-to-many relation in your model using an extra table in your database.

Comment: That's a flag https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-6.0